# Overlapping Text in comments

Tags: bug

I seem to be experiencing a bug with comment text. In some comments, usually at the beginning/end of sentences, the text will overlap. Making the end of one sentence lay on top of the beginning of the next. Somewhat demonstrated here:

[image]

(I'll add a better example if I can find one today)

After inspecting the source for the comments where this occurs I usually find a sentence that has more than one space after a period. This space coincides with where the over lapping text is. Removing the space fixes the over lap. Has this been previously documented?

Answer (score 2):

This is a known issue with SF&F and I think one or two other sites.

I believe it's because the SE network pushed out new style sheets, in conjunction with the enhanced profile pages that were rolled out a few weeks ago.

Unfortunately, there's something about our site's custom styles that conflicts with the new stuff, which is why 1. there's CSS quirky stuff happening, and 2. we don't have the new profile pages.

Sometimes just refreshing the page fixes it.